# How do I prevent looping, unless I press the button, and it shows the next one and so on?

Tags: python, mysql, loops, bots, telegram

how do I show only one message in a loop until I press the button or type, and then it shows the next message?

[picture of it now, its shows all the messages, and I want to create button which only then pressed it shows the next one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEJY9.png)

```
for job in jobs:
        def gen_markup():
            markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            markup.row_width = 1
            markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='לאתר מתגייסים', url=job[3]))
            return markup
        if int(job[6]) <= int(user.dpr) and int(job[7]) <= int(user.profil) and job[4] == user.sex or job[5] == user.sex:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "<b>" + str(job[1]) + "</b>" + "\n" + str(job[2]), reply_markup = gen_markup(), parse_mode='HTML')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this, after the button is clicked it will call the other data with new markup and send message

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_query(call):
    
    def gen_markup():
            markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            markup.row_width = 1
            markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='לאתר מתגייסים', url=job[3]))
            return markup
        
    def gen_marku1p():
            markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            markup.row_width = 1
            markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='לאתר מתגייסים', url=job[3]))
            return markup
        
    def gen_markup2():
            markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            markup.row_width = 1
            markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='לאתר מתגייסים', url=job[3]))
            return markup
        
    if call.data == "markup button text":
        bot.send_message(call.chat.id, 'text', parse_mode="html", reply_markup = gen_markup())
        
    elif call.data == "another markup button text":
        bot.send_message(call.chat.id, 'text', parse_mode="html", reply_markup = gen_markup1())
        
    elif call.data == "another markup button text":
        bot.send_message(call.chat.id, 'text', parse_mode="html", reply_markup = gen_markup2())
```

Comment: I tried but it still sent all the messages, can you contact me on telegram @M_A49 and I will send you the project?

Comment: sure, @elyxus is my username